# Großschreibung (englischer) Übersetzungen in Klammern

Tags: translation

Wenn (englische) Fremdwörter direkt im Text verwendet werden, gelten deutsche Regeln: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen.

Gelten bei Übersetzungen deutscher Wörter in Fremdsprachen in Klammern die Regeln für fremdsprachliche Begriffe in deutschen Texten oder die Regeln der fremden Sprache? Beispiel:

**Kreditkarte (engl. credit card) oder Kreditkarte (engl. Credit Card)?**

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Das Übersetzen ist doch gerade eine Übertragung in die Regeln der anderen Sprache. Denn gälte nach dem Übersetzen die *deutsche* Rechtschreibung, müsste man ja *Kredit* statt *credit* und *Karte* statt *card* schreiben und das Ganze dann auch noch zusammen, womit wir wieder bei *Kreditkarte* wären und nichts gewonnen hätten.

Comment: Man kann Fremdworte ja auch direkt im Text verwenden: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen. Dann gelten "deutsche" Regeln, insbesondere was die Großschreibung betrifft. Aber ich wollte ja eigentlich genau das hören was du gesagt hast: Bei Übersetzungen gelten die Regeln der Zielsprache.

Comment: @SebastianE Die Ergänzung/Abgrenzung aus dem Kommentar sollte in der Frage stehen.

Comment: Steht das da nicht? Ist ergänzt.

Comment: Kurze Antwort: Nein, der Begriff wird exakt so geschrieben wie in der Ursprungssprache. Du zitierst dann quasi aus dem Englischen, daher wird vielfach der fremdsprachliche Begriff auch in Klammern gesetzt: *Kreditkarte (engl. "credit card")*. Ansonsten würde es keinen Sinn **machen** (sic!), den englischen Begriff anzugeben, wie Björn bereits erläuterte. Schön sind in diesem Zusammenhang auch Konstrukte aus pseudo-englischsprachigen Wörtern wie "Handy (engl.: cell phone)"...

Comment: Vielen Dank für eure Antworten. Kann jemand eine Quelle dazu zitieren? @YetiCGN warum (sic!)?

Comment: @SebastianE: weil im Englischen etwas Sinn macht und Leute sagen, im Deutschen kann etwas nur einen Sinn haben und keinen machen.

Comment: @shegit brahm Was allerdings zu beweisen wäre ;) Danke

Comment: @SebastianE Leider finde ich keine Quelle dazu. "Sic" weil "Sinn machen" ein (mittlerweile etablierter) Anglizismus ist, aber ich bin fein damit, wenn den jemand verwendet. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Die Übernahme eines fremdsprachigen Begriffs in die dt. Sprache ist etwas anderes, als die Angabe einer Übersetzung.

Bei der Übersetzung wird es geschrieben wie es in der betreffenden Sprache - hier Englisch - nun mal geschrieben wird. Es bleibt ein fremdsprachiger Begriff, bei der Eingemeindung als Fremdwort dagegen wird es, als Hauptwort, eben groß geschrieben.

Comment: Das mit dem Unterschied zwischen *Begriffsübernahme* und *Übersetzungsangabe* ist ein guter Hinweis.

Comment: Gibt es hierzu eine Quelle?

Comment: @SebastianE: Bestimmt, aber ich habe keine.